# grouping table by multiple factors and spreading it from long format to wide - the data.table way in R

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr

As an example i will be using the `mtcars` data available in R:

```
data(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)
```

Lets day I want to group the data by three variables, namely: `carb`, `cyl`, and `gear`. I have done this as follow. However, i am sure there is a better way, as this is quite repetitive.

```
newDTcars <- mtcars [, mtcars[, mtcars[, .N , by = carb], by = cyl], by= gear]
```

Secondly, I would like to have the data in a wide format, where there is a separate column for every `gear` level. For illustration purpose I have done this using `tidyr`, however i would like to have this done the "data.table" way.

```
newDTcars %>% tidyr::spread(gear, N)
```

The emphasis of this question is to keep to solution to the data.table world, as i would like too learn more about `data.table`.

Comment: maybe `dat[, .N, by=c("var1", "var2", "var3")]` for your first step. Then use `dcast` to reshape wide.

Comment: Do you need `dcast(mtcars[, .N, .(carb, cyl, gear)], carb+cyl~gear, value.var = "N")` ?

Comment: @RonakShah exactly. Could you write it as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `data.table`, we can group by multiple columns and to reshape we can use `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(mtcars[, .N, .(carb, cyl, gear)], carb+cyl~gear, value.var = "N")

#   carb cyl  3  4  5
#1:    1   4  1  4 NA
#2:    1   6  2 NA NA
#3:    2   4 NA  4  2
#4:    2   8  4 NA NA
#5:    3   8  3 NA NA
#6:    4   6 NA  4 NA
#7:    4   8  5 NA  1
#8:    6   6 NA NA  1
#9:    8   8 NA NA  1
```

You may use `fill` argument in `dcast` to replace `NA`s with 0 or any other number.

Comment: answer is absolutely correct. I just wanted to say that you can pass the `dcast` as an argument of the *j* part of a chained data.table expression: `mtcars[, .N, by = .(carb, cyl, gear)][, dcast(.SD, carb+cyl ~ gear, value.var = "N")]`. It will run with no noticeable loss of performance.